# React Native: Using props in const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm new to react/react native and trying to build a simple app that plays local MP3. I'm using the react-native-sound module which seems to work really well.

Though now, I'm trying to pass `fileName` as props from my category to the player component.
It seems like that react-native-sound requires me preload a sound file. Thus, now I get the following error:

> "Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'fileName' of
>   undefined".

```
...    
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const play = new Sound(this.props.fileName, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
  } else { // loaded successfully
    console.log('duration in seconds: ' + play.getDuration() +
        'number of channels: ' + play.getNumberOfChannels());
  }
});

export default class playTrack extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        playing: false,
        track: this.props.fileName,
      };
    }

    playTrack() {
      this.setState({playing: true})
      play.play((success) => {
        if (success) {
          console.log('successfully finished playing');
        } else {
          console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
        }
      })
    }
...
```

Do you have any pointers for me how to go about this?

Comment: There are no `this.props` outside of the component class definition.

Comment: In the third line, you contract 'Sound' with this.props.filename but 'this' refers to the window and have no props

Comment: Lexical scoping ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to your class instance's `this` from outside the class the way you are trying to use it. Instead, create the `Sound` in the constructor:

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

export default class playTrack extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.play = new Sound(props.fileName, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) = > {
            if (error) {
                console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
            } else { // loaded successfully
                console.log('duration in seconds: ' + this.play.getDuration() +
                    'number of channels: ' + this.play.getNumberOfChannels());
            }
        });

        this.state = {
            playing: false,
            track: this.props.fileName,
        };
    }

    playTrack() {
        this.setState({
            playing: true
        })
        this.play.play((success) = > {
            if (success) {
                console.log('successfully finished playing');
            } else {
                console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Things start to make sense. Thank you Timo.

Comment: The only addition that I made to your suggested code was a `const play = null;` before the component class definition. Now it works! Thanks

Comment: @Jonas Defining `play` outside your component really shouldn't be necesssary!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You are 100% right. The only reason why I still got an error was that `play.getDuration()` and `play.getNumberOfChannels()` were missing a `this.`